# Emberjs: Use args as tracked property

Tags: ember.js

I am doing a store query in the `controller` and then passing the result down to a child component.

```
// Controller
@tracked comment;

@action
async fetchComment() {
  const comment = await this.store.query('note', {
    filter: {
      listing: this.listing.id,
    },
  });

  if (comment && comment.length > 0) {
    this.comment = comment.firstObject;
  }
}


// Template
<MyComponent @comment={{this.comment}} />
```

I want to use the arg to populate a tracked property in the child component.

```
// Component
@tracked comment = this.args.comment;
```

I found this does not work but works well as a getter. However with a getter I am unable to set this to null when deleting that record.

I have also tried to set the tracked property in the `Constructor` but that didnt work either.

I suspect this has something to do with passing in a `promise` or `store object` in the args because this works fine with static data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### why your code does not work

this code can not work:

```
@tracked comment = this.args.comment;
```

this is because `comment` on the controller is initially `undefined` but will later bet set to `comment.firstObject` when the network request is done and the `await` in your `fetchComment` function returns.
Generally everythings on `args` basically always behaves like its `@tracked` (while more accurate you would describe it as getters). So this usually will just update fine. But the assignment `@tracked comment = this.args.comment;` only happens *once* when you create the component, so you no longer depend on updates on `args`.

### why you can not set `this.args.comment` to null

If you use a getter or directly always use `this.args.comment` you can not change this reference. This is because `this.args` is always readonly. you can *change* objects on `this.args.something`, but you never can change the reference or primitive value on `this.args`.

Sidenote: this is only true if the component was called with `<AngleBracket />` syntax. For the older `{{curly-component}}` syntax this is not true. So this does not depend on the component itself but how the component gets called.

### you could notify the controller to remove the reference

one *good* thing to do is to pass down a `deleteComment` action to the component that basically does something like `this.comment = null` on the controller. then you use `this.args.comment` directly or by a getter and you can call `this.args.deleteComment()` to set `comment` on the controller to null, which will update anything that uses `this.args.comment` or a getter that returns `this.args.comment`.

this is essentially because in your architecture the controller *owns* the data (because it loads it). so the controller is also responsible to delete it.

### if you use `ember-data` you can check `isDeleted`

if its a `ember-data` model (which it probably is if you call `this.store`) then it has a [`isDeleted`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/3.26/classes/Model/properties/isDeleted?anchor=isDeleted) property. you can use this to check if the record is deleted, since `ember-data` records dont disappear if they get deleted. which is exactly because of problems like this.

### how you use another property to *shadow* a argument

you could do something like this to *shadow* an argument in your component:

```
@tracked commentIsDeleted = false;
get comment() {
  return this.commentIsDeleted
    ? null
    : this.args.comment;
}
```

this way at first `this.comment` will work like a normal getter, but you can *shadow delete* it by setting `this.commentIsDeleted = true;`. From that on `this.comment` will be `null`.

Comment: Wow thanks so much, lots to try out. That shadow delete trick is awesome. Thank you